# Previous owner removed the entire parking brake system on my car, what are my options?

Tags: manual-transmission, parking-brake, porsche

The title says most of it, the previous owner removed the ENTIRE parking brake system in my 1983 manual Porsche 944 for whatever reason, and I need to replace it because I don't really want it to keep rolling down the driveway. Looking around on Ebay and whatnot I was able to fine a good amount of the parts, albeit not cheap, and I cant help but wonder if I cant just tap into the normal break lines or get a parking brake designed for another car. Is any of that stuff possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, you could also leave it parked in gear, depending on how steep your driveway is.  I have a manual, and I don't use the parking brake.  Your mileage may vary..

Comment: @Cullub that's what the previous owner probably did, but I swapped in an electric motor instead of an engine so that doesn't work anymore

Comment: That's awesome!  I suppose there's no equivalent with the electric motors then.  Could you clarify how much "the entire parking brake system" is?  Handle?  Cables?  Wire paths?  Different disks on the back now?

Comment: @Cullub literally all of it is gone, he removed everything from the handle to the shoe

Comment: Just to clarify, your rear rotors are still stock shape?  As in, they have room for the parking brake inside still?

Comment: @Cullub yeah it's still got the brake rotors, but there is no separate parking brake disk present, and I can't tell if it had one originally

Comment: FYI, parking brakes (your car included) use drum brakes inside the regular rotors on the back, not separate rotors.

Comment: @Cullub huh, I'm no expert but I'll go out and check if I can find them

Comment: You'd have to take off the rotors to get to them, but if they're still there, that'll make things a lot easier (and cheaper!).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94917/discussion-on-question-by-yanagibashi-previous-owner-removed-the-entire-parking).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you'll have much luck trying to use other cars' brake systems.  Here's what a parking brake system generally consists of:

- Handle
- A splitter to split the one handle into two cables
- The cables that attach to the splitter, and run all the way back to the rear wheels (separately).
- A drum brake system inside each rear rotor (connects to the wires, and is bolted to the frame somehow)

You still have the regular brake rotors, and you'll need to keep those so the rest of your normal brake system works.  You'll need drum brakes specifically for your car, since those are the ones that will bolt to the frame and fit inside the rotor nicely.

The cables you could swap out, but then you'll run into problems with them being the same length, and those can't be that expensive (right?).  The splitter could be swapped out too, but that's a pretty small piece and it'd be easier to keep it the same if you can.  And the handle could be swapped, but if you like your car to look normal, you might want to keep the same handle.  Besides, each handle attaches a little differently, and it'd be a pain to attach a new one IMO.

Comment: About the last point: There are also cars where the parking brake acts on the disc.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  Didn't know that.  I'll leave this as is since I'm not really familiar with those, but if you'd like to edit feel free!

Answer (score 0):

If you're searching eBay for parts for a 1984 Porsche 944 only, you may be limiting your options.  The brake rotor and shoes for that car also match for a 1983-1986 Porsche 944, 1977-1988 Porsche 924, and a 1978-1985 Porsche 928.  I'm not very familiar with Porsches, but there are good odds that these other models use many of the same parts as your 1984 944—certainly the shoes and rotors are the same!  So expanding your search *may* put cheaper parts in your reach.